# View mesh in OpenGL (lwjgl)

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL. I'm trying to create a simple 3D map using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP and it works fine. But now OpenGL automatically fills up every triangle. I was wondering if it is possible for OpenGL to only draw the outlines of each triangle. This way I have a better view on what I'm doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`glPolygonMode()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPolygonMode.xml) to disable fills on front and backward facing geometry:

```
// enable wireframe
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT, GL_LINE );

// draw stuff to be wireframe'd
DrawStuff();

// restore regular rendering
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT, GL_FILL );
```